# Keep header 100% height no matter what navbar size

Tags: css

When I have a navbar as seperate div, how can I make the header full height of the screen? When I add 100vh it's too big, when users lands on website he can scroll. I need to add like 95.5vh instead to fit it perfectly, but I do not want to add custom height. How can I make it to be full height all time no matter the size of navbar? Is there something else than vh I could use?

```css
header {
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar__logo">Brand.</div>
  </div>
  <header>
    Hello
  </header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex), [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) and [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) does the job well.

[Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) would be a good reading to have. Then seach MDN for more detail of each property.

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar__logo">Brand.</div>
</div>
<header>
  Hello
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the issue. Can I use flex; 1 instead flex-grow?

Comment: Yes... In the flex documentation it says: `This property is a shorthand for the following CSS properties:

flex-grow
flex-shrink
flex-basis`

Comment: Note that there is the `flex` value for the display property... And the `flex` property... Two different things. lol. There is a lack of naming creativity here hahah